Ingress controller in AKS not routing properly
I have an aks cluster, where i have a spring boot REST API deployed, connected to a psql service.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springboot-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: springboot-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: springboot-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: springboot-app
        image: someImage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
          value: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/student
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-secret
              key: username
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-secret
              key: password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: springboot-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: springboot-app

And here is a part of the controller class of the API:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/product")
public class ProductController {

    private final ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "products")
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return productService.getProducts();
    }

I wanted to expose the API to the internet, so I installed the nginx controller and I created an ingress file:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster.issuer: letsencrypt-staging
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  generation: 2
  name: aks-helloworld
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: springboot-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix

When I exec to the spring API pod and try to curl the resources like so
curl http://localhost:8080/api/product/products

It works fine and returns correct output.
However, when i try to connect to the api, using the public static ip from the nginx controller, I get the spring white labaled error page, 404 not found
http://<public-ip>/api/product/products

And the ingress controller logs say that
[05/Jul/2024:08:57:56 +0000] "GET /api/product/products HTTP/1.1" 404 306 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/111.0.0.0" 489 0.005 [default-springboot-service-80]

And also there aren't any mentions of that call. in the spring API pod logs, unlike when I'm using curl within the pod itself. I'm new to the k8s`, and any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong, would be much appreciated.
Also worth mentioning, when I deployed the aks-helloworld image from this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing?tabs=default%2Cdeploy-app-default
I could connec through the public ip no problem.

I'd check if I could curl the api from another pod in another namespace through the fqdn of the spring boot service.

You can cross verify your ingress and service template specifically compare the port mapping. It should match with your application.properties file in your springboot.
Assuming you have your application already available in your acr,

create your springboot-deployment, service and ingress yaml
Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springboot-app
  labels:
    app: springboot-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: springboot-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: springboot-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: springboot-app
        image: arkoacr.azurecr.io/my-spring-boot-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8091
        env:
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
          value: jdbc:postgresql://postgres-postgresql.postgres.svc.cluster.local:5432/student
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
          value: arko
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
          value: Welcome@12345
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /greeting
            port: 8091
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 5
        imagePullSecrets:
        - name: acr-secret

service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: springboot-service
  labels:
    app: springboot-app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8091
  selector:
    app: springboot-app



Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: springboot-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /greeting
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: springboot-service
            port:
              number: 80





If you are still facing issue, then check the  kubectl describe ingress <ingress-name>  to check the configuration of your ingress resource along with  kubectl describe service <service-name>  to check the configuration of your service and also the  kubectl logs <nginx-controller-pod-name>
References:

Troubleshoot common questions or issues with Ingress Controller
Best practices for network connectivity and security in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)


Feldmarshall is your issue resolved?
